# Why getAction method always return ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I am using onTouchListener for a layout. I want to take the click outside the layout. I set onTouchListetener for the layout. But motion event always shows ACTION_DOWN. Even i touchOutside the view, It is not showing ACTION_OUTSIDE. Could anyone help me to find out why it is not showing constant ACTION_OUTSIDE. Here is the code i am using

```
Layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("action",event.getAction()+"");
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you return `false`, then you're signifying that you do not wish to receive further touch events. You need to return `true` to continue getting motion events.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple to fix by adding this:

```
 override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The event listener itself listens to one event action at a time. The first of course is the ACTION.DOWN, in which your toast shows.

Just like what Jason Robinson and user936414, you have to return it to true so that the object or the listener could here the second event action, ACTION.OUTSIDE.

Answer (score 0):

You will get ACTION_OUTSIDE when the touch is outside the activity and the flag FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH is set. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH

Comment: :But can we set  FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE for a linear layout?

Comment: @gorbos i returned true, now i am getting values 0,1,2 that is ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP,ACTION_MOVE. Not getting ACTION_OUTSIDE