# Enter event key is responding only from the second time in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to make operations when the user presses on the enter key but only once. My problem is the said operation is happening only when I press the enter key twice. Here is my code:

```
EditText spin3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spin3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {

                if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                {
                        loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                        try {
                            authenticate3();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return true;

                }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML code of my editText

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="331dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="numero de facture"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.397"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, immediately creating alert dialog after

```
if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
{  
     getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    (alert dialog call) ...
```

And the dialog is called after just 1 enter. So this method is working......

Apparently, after some searches, this type of question has been asked a few times on stackoverflow.

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513888/enter-key-on-edittext-hitting-onkey-twice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116910/why-getaction-method-always-return-action-down)
, it may be that you return true in the enter & down condition which implies further event detection (up and movement).

So for it to stop, return false. However, if this doesn't work, please check the authenticate3() method.

```
EditText spin3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spin3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {

                if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                {
                        loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                        try {
                            authenticate3();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return false;

                }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i remove *getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)* line but it does not work